# React MUI Button onClick does not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, onclick

I am currently working on to create a Page3 component. Below is the code.

```
 /**
 * Component for the third page of about page.
 */

 // React
 import React, { useState} from 'react';
 import TeamMembers from './TeamMembers';
 // Material UI
 import { Box, Button, Typography, Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent } from '@mui/material';

 // Global Styles
 const page3WrapperStyle = {
   display: 'flex',
   flexDirection: 'column',
   justifyContent: 'center', 
   alignItems: 'center',
   padding: 4,
   height: '100vh', 
 };

 const dialogTitleStyle = {
   textAlign: 'center',
 };

 /**
  * React Functional Component for About page's third page
  * @return {React.ReactElement} Renders third page of about page
  */
 function Page3(): React.ReactElement {
   const [showTeamMembers, setShowTeamMembers] = useState(false);

   const handleButtonClick = () => {
     console.log("Meet Our Team button clicked");
     setShowTeamMembers(!showTeamMembers);
   };

   return (
     <Box sx={page3WrapperStyle}>
       <Typography variant="h1" color="red.main" align="center" sx={{position: 'absolute', top: '60px'}}>
         About Our Team
       </Typography>
       <Typography variant="body1" sx={{ mb: 5 }} align="center">
         We are a passionate team dedicated to enhancing the college experience.
       </Typography>
       <Button variant="contained" sx={{ textTransform: 'none'}} onClick={handleButtonClick}>
         Meet Our Team
       </Button>
       <Dialog open={showTeamMembers} onClose={handleButtonClick}>
         <DialogTitle sx={dialogTitleStyle}>Team Members</DialogTitle>
         <DialogContent>
           <TeamMembers />
         </DialogContent>
       </Dialog>
     </Box>
   );
 }

 export default React.memo(Page3);
```

However, onClick property does not works if I clicked the Button. I am not sure what I am missing. I have tried many different way but could not find the way why it does not work. Can anyone give me an idea why it does not works?

```
 <Button variant="contained" sx={{ textTransform: 'none'}} onClick={handleButtonClick}>
         Meet Our Team
       </Button>
```

Comment: maybe the padding of the first Typography component (with `position: absolute`) is covering this button? Do you see the hover/click visual effect on the button?

Comment: @norbnik I am not sure if thats the problem. I deleted the "position: absolute"and tried it but it did not work. Also, hover effect does not work neither for the button.

Comment: If you can't see the hover effect, then I guess it's covered by another element. Try clicking on the button with your right mouse button and select "inspect element". This should show you the HTML element that is covering the button.

Comment: I have tried to look it using chrome developer. However, not sure how I can identify whats cover the button. is there anyway I can share what it show on my google chorme HTML code? What I have seen, nothing is covered but not sure if I did correctly.

Comment: You can share a part of your project that shows this issue, for example using CodeSandbox.

You can try using Chrome DevTools in the following way:
- open the devtools
- click the dotted square with arrow button in the top left corner of devtools (or press Ctrl+Shift+C)
- click on the button on the page
- if it shows you the button element in HTML, it's not covered and the issue is somewhere else. If it shows something different, then the button is covered by this thing.

Comment: @norbnik Thank you for the advice! was able to solve it with your adivce :)